# How to retrive the array value into different array?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsarray

In my application , i have used the Json.This is my JSON response in my application

```
This is my Response:
[
    {
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "userId": "1",
    "userCompany": "xxxyy",
    "userName": "sham",
    "userAddress": "chennai",
    "userCity": "xxxxx",
    "userMobile": "xxxx",
    "userEmail": "xxx"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "productImage": "http://www.iii.jpg",
    "productDescription": "Loaded box on pallets - Bart's package",
    "productCost": "10",
    "productBoxWeight": "10.0"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "1.4",
    "transportCountry": "Colombia",
    "transportPort": "Havana"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "0.7",
    "transportCountry": "Brazil",
    "transportPort": "Santos"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "0.9",
    "transportCountry": "South Africa",
    "transportPort": "Durban"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "0.9",
    "transportCountry": "Chili",
    "transportPort": "San Antonio"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "2.7",
    "transportCountry": "Australia",
    "transportPort": "Maersk"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "1",
    "transportCountry": "Marocco",
    "transportPort": "Casablanca"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "1",
    "transportCountry": "Kuwait",
    "transportPort": "Shuwaikh"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "1",
    "transportCountry": "Jordan",
    "transportPort": "Aqaba"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "0.8",
    "transportCountry": "Saoudi Arabia",
    "transportPort": "Jeddah"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "0.8",
    "transportCountry": "Malta",
    "transportPort": "Maraxklokk"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "0.9",
    "transportCountry": "Mexico",
    "transportPort": "Veracruz"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "1.2",
    "transportCountry": "Thailand",
    "transportPort": "Bangkok"
},
{
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "transportCost": "1",
    "transportCountry": "Thailand",
    "transportPort": "havana"
}
]
```

How can i retrive first two set in one array and other sets in another array...i'm new to this please help me to fix it...

Comment: can u pls give me correct info what u need exatctly from that response ?@IOSdev

Comment: {
    "response": "Success",
    "errorMsg": "",
    "userId": "1",
    "userCompany": "xxxyy",
    "userName": "sham",
    "userAddress": "chennai",
    "userCity": "xxxxx",
    "userMobile": "xxxx",
    "userEmail": "xxx"
},i need to separate each set like this...

Comment: change your response like key : value manner then read response and save in JsonArray. based on key you can manage response to save appropriate array.

Comment: Is it possible to change your response ?

Comment: ur json format not a correct format dear ..pls check in jsonlint or jsonviewer?

Comment: @Anjaneyulu it is correct (ignoring the "This is my Response:")

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not define the keys or values (including values in JSON's array) to be in any order. Therefore you'll have to sort the items yourself after parsing.

And in order to parse JSON you can use [any JSON parser available](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+parser+json) (I prefer SBJson).
Usually parsers provide possibility to convert JSON to [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) so you can easily deal with its content.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse your JSON and get Objective-C objects, use the following piece of code (where `data` is the JSON you just got):

```
NSError *e = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                          error:&e];
```

After that you'll have a `NSArray` containing multiple dictionaries (`NSDictionary`). To get the first one, do:

```
if (!jsonArray) {
  NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
    // get the first dictionary
    NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];    
}
```